# Find elements in an xml dom where two attribute correspond to certain values using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I have:

```
<drug_list>
  <drug id='4' supplier_id='4'></drug>
  <drug id='1' supplier_id='2'></drug>
  <drug id='21' supplier_id='45'></drug>
  <drug id='1' supplier_id='7'></drug>
</drug_list>
```

How do i use jQuery to get the drug with id of "1" and supplier_id of "2"?

Comment: I was able to work it out with one .find("requisition_detail[drugId='" + drugId + "']"), but having problem with 2.

Comment: You can use two attribute filters in a row: [id="1"][supplier_id="2"] http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
$('drug').each(function(){
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var supplier_id = $(this).attr('supplier_id');
if(id==1 && supplier_id==2)  {
///do something
}  
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For reference see: [this](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-attribute-selector/)

```
//Do whatever to get the xml (simulating getting from somewhere here).
var $xml = $("<drug_list><drug id='4' supplier_id='4'>abc</drug><drug id='1' supplier_id='2'>def</drug></drug_list>");

//make sure to pass the xml as context to the selector (2nd param).
$("drug[id='1'][supplier_id='2']", $xml).each(function() {
    $this = $(this);
    //do whatever you want with $this i.e. $this.text() or $this.attr("id")...
  });
```

Comment: +1 It work. I'll have to accept Vivek answer because it came first. Thanks.

Comment: @Colour Blend - for future reference, I believe SO best practice is to accept the best solution rather than the first and vote up any solutions that were helpful. That way we encourage the most informative answers rather than merely the quickest. This isn't a comment on the relative merits of the two answers provided.